Flutter Serverpod upload image file
When I upload an image file to Serverpod's cloud storage for testing. I noticed that the URL that is being returned from the Upload Description (and subsequently saved to my record) is not directly useable in the app UI (for example trying to display a simple network image). What I require is
http://localhost:8080/serverpod_cloud_storage?method=upload&storage=public&path=qAHRhQkmxj0el5Gv.jpg
what is being returned is
http://localhost:8080/serverpod_cloud_storage?method=upload&storage=public&path=qAHRhQkmxj0el5Gv.jpg&key=9PCDsuO74gwXf9tU
This is due to "&key=9PCDsuO74gwXf9tU" a key or something being appended to the end of the URL. Should I just be cropping the returned string or have I done something wrong?

You'll need to get the publicUrl for the uploaded file. Which you can do by following the documentation in the serverpod docs -> https://docs.serverpod.dev/concepts/file-uploads . Also make sure you verify the upload is completed before trying to get a public url

@VipinKumarKashyap thanks for the comment, I will give it another try once I find some time.
